# what will happen if i store collection of data into the instance variable under initialize method?

Tags: ruby

what will happen if i store collection of data into instance variable under initialize method?

when i create the object of the class, instance variable are there in the object with lots of data. 
I want to understand how it slow down the execution.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking what the effect is of storing data in an instance variable is? The effect is that the memory usage of the instance of the class will go up. But if those objects already exist in memory somewhere else then Ruby will store pointers to the data, not duplicates of the data. You should include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you want specific answers; since your question does not include one I have voted to close it.

Comment: @anothermh, i updated the description. plz have a look now.

Comment: You have not updated the question. If you want to edit your question to add more information you must click the "edit" link at the bottom of your question.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether or not you make a new copy of the data before passing it to initialize. Given a class like this:

```
class MyClass
  attr_accessor :big_list
  def initialize(big_list)
    @big_list = big_list
  end
end

big_list = (0..1_000_000).to_a
```

This will only store the `big_list` in memory once:

```
inst = MyClass.new(big_list)
```

Since the instance variable in the class and the original `big_list` variable are the same object, changing one alters both:

```
inst.big_list.clear
puts big_list.length # => 0
```

It's a different story if you completely re-assign one of the variables, because then they're pointing to different objects (and additional memory will be used)

```
inst.big_list = [1,2,3]
puts big_list.length # => 0
```

The same thing would happen if you passed a different list to initialize:

```
inst = MyClass.new(big_list + big_list)
puts inst.big_list.length == big_list.length # => false
```

In this case two lists would be stored in memory, not one.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to understand how it slow down the execution.

If you are asking if doing something in a `initialize` can slow down execution, then yes. When you call the `new` method the code inside that block will run and not return until it is completed.

For example the following should show how code in `initialize` will slow down code execution.

```
class Foo 
    def initialize(n)
        sleep n 
    end
end

puts "slow down with sleep"
puts Time.now 
Foo.new(0)
puts Time.now 
Foo.new(1)
puts Time.now 

class Bar 
    def initialize(n)
        @a = []
        (0..n).each { |i| @a<<i } 
    end
end

puts "slow down with work"
puts Time.now 
Bar.new(0)
puts Time.now 
Bar.new(100000000)
puts Time.now
```